# Why does Azure recommend User Delegation Shared Access Signatures

Tags: azure, security, azure-storage

In the Microsoft documentation, it is recommended that professionals use User Delegation Shared Access Signatures rather than key-based Shared Access Signatures. Specifically, why is this the case?

In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview), it is specified that:

> Microsoft recommends that you use Azure AD credentials when possible
> as a security best practice, rather than using the account key, which
> can be more easily compromised. When your application design requires
> shared access signatures for access to Blob storage, use Azure AD
> credentials to create a user delegation SAS when possible for superior
> security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Azure official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#authorization-of-a-user-delegation-sas) explains why it is recommended to use User Delegation Shared Access Signatures.

> When a client accesses a blob service resource with a user delegation SAS, the request to Azure Storage is authorized with the Azure AD credentials that were used to create the SAS. The role-based access control (RBAC) permissions granted for that Azure AD account, together with the permissions explicitly granted on the SAS, determine the client's access to the resource. This approach provides an additional level of security and avoids the need to store your account access key with your application code. For these reasons, creating a SAS using Azure AD credentials is a security best practice.

Comment: I have created a key-based SAS and a user based SAS. Neither of these SAS has the account key included in it. The key is not in my source. Does Microsoft think that it possible to reverse the process that created the SAS to produce the key?

Comment: Hi, @alwaysLearning. Here are some of my personal opinions:

In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m58O.png), we can see that the `key` was used when generating the `Account SAS`. There may be some risks and some possibilities that the key will be obtained, maybe as you said in the comments. 

However, generating `User delegation SAS` goes through the following four [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#authorization-of-a-user-delegation-sas).

It's more secure and reliable.